# jquery jcarousel not scrolling through all items

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

i have 21 items in the list, but scrolling by hitting the right(next) icon only takes me to the 13th item and stops.

any ideas?

link is below, thanks in advance for any assistance.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2483833/shareCarousel/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, forgot to style the generated divs, the following css fixed it:

```
.jcarousel-container{ width: 1400px }
.jcarousel-clip-horizontal{ width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto 20px }
```